# Flask - How to upload multiple images to a database and render them on a website

Tags: python, html, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an image upload area with Flask. This area can also load multiple images. There are up to 8 image upload tracks. After uploading the saved images, I put them in the file. I'll post the images they upload again on the site. I'm thinking of registering it in the database, but I don't know how to register it. I want pictures with input file. How many pictures have been uploaded and I do not understand how to draw these pictures.

In short, when the user saves the images that are saved, I keep it in the file and I want to save the uploaded images to the database for publishing on my site. How can I do that? I'm using SQLalchemy.

HTML;

```
 <input id="files" name="files" type="file" multiple>
```

Python;

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

class AlbumForm(Form):
    files = FileField(render_kw={'multiple': True})

#Album form
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/admin/fotografAlbumu", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload():
    form = AlbumForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'files' in request.files:
        for f in request.files.getlist('files'):
            files = form.files.data
            username = session["username"]
            url=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+username
            f.save(os.path.join(url, f.filename))
        return render_template('/admin/galeri.html',form=form)
    return render_template('/admin/galeri.html',form=form)

@app.route('/uploaded_file/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    print(filename)
    username = session["username"]
    url=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+username
    return send_from_directory(url, filename)
```

The database structure I think is as follows;

```
class Album(db.Model):
    albumid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.userid'))
    fotoOne = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoTwo = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoThree = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoFour = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoFive = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoSix = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoSeven = db.Column(db.String(80))
    fotoEight = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Comment: It's not a very good idea to store files in a database. Store only the metadata that you need. And also looks how sqlalchemy works.

Answer (score 1):

For you to render the images, get the album then access the images as attributes i.e. `album.foto_one`, `album.foto_two` and so on:

```
@app.route('/show-album/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_album(id=None):
try:
    album = Album.query.get(id)
    return render_template('album.html', album=album)
except:
    abort(404)
```

Then in `album.html`:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('/static/uploads/album.foto_one }}">
<img src="{{ url_for('/static/uploads/album.foto_two }}">
```

You can also store the image names as an array and render them as follows:

```
class Album(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    photos = db.Column(ARRAY(String))
```

And in your template iterate over the photos list instead of typing all the links.

```
{% for item in album.photos %}
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static/uploads/item') }}"> # <img src="/static/uploads/image_name.jpeg">
    </li>
</ul>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: The actual image file is saved in the static folder via the line `file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_FILES'], filename))` you only have to store the image names on the database column photos then access them via `url_for`.